# IFrame Video in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video, iframe, modal-dialog

I just want a video which has been embedded in a modal using iframe, stops when the modal is closed. Is this possible using JavaScript?

| Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by adding an iframe tag in the modal body

```
<iframe src="your_video.mp4"></iframe>
```